# Keras: prediction of matches in a series of numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-science, prediction

I try to predict hits in a sequence of numbers, but it is important to me not to predict hits that already exist. For example, I have a sequence of numbers from 1 to 100000. And for some of these numbers I have hit, now I would like to predict even more hits. Which method is suitable for this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is mainly for questions related to programming problems. Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to know more about what topics you can ask about here. [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) would be more suitable for your question.

Comment: @athraa I always had the opinion that non-linear program design is a gray zone between data science and programming. As per my experience Data Science folks are more into statistics and I usually received much more help in here about how NNs work.

Comment: @Manngo can't agree I am afraid. I think the link in my above comment says it all about what questions are more suitable to be asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem statement is very high level. What I understand that Neural Networks are doing what you need. Neural Nets take input data that is already classified as hit or not hit. Then they can learn what is a hit. Then you can feed as much data as you want and the learned rules will be applied on the new data. If you want to learn more just go [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?reload=9&list=PLjy4p-07OYzulelvJ5KVaT2pDlxivl_BN), or update your question.